# Javascript medium-editor markdown append image and update content

Tags: javascript, jquery, markdown, medium-editor

```
<div class="editable" contenteditable="true"></div>
<textarea name="markdown" class="markdown" /></textarea>//display none

new MediumEditor('.editable', {
    extensions: {
        markdown: new MeMarkdown(function (md) {
            document.querySelector(".markdown").textContent = md;
        }),
        img: new imgButton()
    }


$('.editable').append("<img src='abc' />");
```

I have a div use medium-editor & medium-editor markdown

when user type inside of `.editable`, `textarea` will sync.

I also have a button click, it will append an image into `.editable`

my problem is markdown only update when `.editable keypress`

so if I append text, `textarea` wont sync, unless I press any key inside of `.editable` again

anyone know how to tell markdown to update after append image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
function updateTextArea(index,editable){
    var textarea = editable.parentNode.querySelector('textarea[medium-editor-textarea-id="' + editable.getAttribute('medium-editor-textarea-id') + '"]');
    if (textarea) {
        textarea.value = editable.innerHTML.trim();
    }
}

$('.editable').append("<img src='abc' />");
$('.editable').each(updateTextArea);
```

The `updateTextArea` function will update a text area corresponds to editable area.

Here is the code I tried

```js
var editor = new MediumEditor('.editable', {
            buttonLabels: 'fontawesome'
        });
           function updateTextArea(index,editable){
                var textarea = editable.parentNode.querySelector('textarea[medium-editor-textarea-id="' + editable.getAttribute('medium-editor-textarea-id') + '"]');
                if (textarea) {
                    textarea.value = editable.innerHTML.trim();
                }
            }
    $("#addImage").click(function(){
      $('.editable').append("<img src='abc' />");
      $('.editable').each(updateTextArea);
     });
$('.editable').change(updateTextArea);
```

```html
<link href="http://yabwe.github.io/medium-editor/bower_components/medium-editor/dist/css/themes/tim.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://yabwe.github.io/medium-editor/bower_components/medium-editor/dist/css/medium-editor.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://yabwe.github.io/medium-editor/bower_components/medium-editor/dist/js/medium-editor.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="container">
        <h1>Medium Editor</h1>
        <textarea class="editable medium-editor-textarea" name="markdown" id="markdown">&lt;p&gt;Textarea is now supported&lt;/p&gt;</textarea>
        <input type="button" id="addImage" value="Add Image">
       <input type="button" value="Alert textarea content" onclick="alert(document.getElementById('markdown').value)">
    </div>
```

Comment: wow thx a lot! it works, but i got a question, your updateTextArea(index,editable) has 2 param, how come u didnt pass any into it $('.editable').each(updateTextArea);

Comment: `$(selector).each` call's the function with two parameters they are index and element. The jquery selector selects all matching elements and for each one of the element it calls specified function with index and element. If the code met your needs please accept the answer.

Comment: the other problem is after it, my textarea is not sync anymore, so when i type text after image append, no more markdown text shows

Comment: Add `$('.editable').change(updateTextArea);` and it will work. I have made changes in the solution and its working now.

Comment: you should add at the end, run above code snippet I have given and see.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `setContent()` method of the editor (documentation [here](https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor/blob/master/API.md#setcontenthtml-index)), this will allow you to add content and the editor will detect the change and fire all the proper events.  This should include notifying the markdown extension that the content has changed and that should update the markdown.

So, instead of this:

```
$('.editable').append('<img src="abc" />');
```

Try this:

```
editor.setContent(editor.getContent() + '<img src="abc" />');
```

This also leverages the `getContent()` method (documentation [here](https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor/blob/master/API.md#getcontentindex)).

NOTE: These examples assume you're only using a single editor element for MediumEditor.  If you are passing multiple elements into a single instance of MediumEditor, you may need to specify a value for the `index` parameter to both `setContent()` and `getContent()`